# Python gets confused by SQL's `LIKE '%something%'` and `%(something)s`

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pandas

I'm executing some SQL queries using `pandas.read_sql()`; to pass parameters I use `params` to pass a python dictionary, so the line looks like

```py
df = pd.read_sql(sql_query, conn, params=params_dict)
```

`params_dict` looks like:

```py
params_dict = {'params1': params1,
               'params2': params2
              }
```

Thus, in query, I can write like

```sql
AND create_time >= %(params1)s
AND create_time < %(params2)s
```

When I run the code, it gets an error, "not enough arguments for format string", after some digging in the code I figured the line below in the SQL query is what caused it:

```sql
AND sign LIKE '%banner%'
```

It seems to me that it's python mistakenly believes `%banner%` is similar to `%(params1)s` so it should find the corresponding argument in the `params_dict`, but in fact it is just SQL wildcard characters.

Is there a way to fix this issue? I know I can simply add it to `params_dict` but I want to find a more elegant way to solve it first.

I'm running Python 3.9

Comment: Escape it: `’%%banner%%’`

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen works! Thanks a lot!